# Java: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: reader cannot be resolved

Tags: java, exception

My code:

```
  package vmd;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class vmd1911 
{
 public static void main (String[] args)
 {
 System.out.print("Type the integer");
     int number = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
     System.out.print("You typed" + number);
         }
}
```

The error: *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    reader cannot be resolved
    at vmd.vmd1911.main(vmd1911.java:10)*

My goal is to do working code of 7.2 in MOOC https://materiaalit.github.io/2013-oo-programming/part1/week-1/

Comment: did your code pass compilation?

Comment: It doesn't matter what are you writing your code for. It seems that your code doesn't pass compilation as mentioned. Where do you declare the `reader` variable?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `reader`.
Add this to your main method:

```
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
```